# Javascript sorting a csv rows and displaying in table

Tags: javascript, algorithm, csv, sorting

I have a csv file which has this format:

```
Major;2;4;29
```

Major should be displayed on the 4 row 2 column.
The file can have a lot nof rows!
I have created this:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),

    readFile = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
    };

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);

<style type="text/css">
output {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 4em;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: .8em;
}
</style>
```

which basically takes a csv file as an input and prints all as it is raw!How can I work and divide the rows on the ";"?And I also want an honest answer what level is this for?(intern,senior?)

Comment: `4 row on the 2-nd line`, you meant 4th column on 2nd line?

Comment: You might want to look into a CSV reader to prevent reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @gurvinder372 4 row 2 column

Comment: You'd normally split on carriage return to get an array of the lines, then split on the character ";" to get the values. Read the values, then go to [*table.rows\[rowIndex\]*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) and insert the value into [*row.cells\[cellIndex\]*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement). Have a go.

Comment: @RobG I understand the logic the problem is translating logic into code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trivial example, it's fairly straight forward. The issue will be splitting the data, it's pretty simple if the data is simple and the delimiter unique. But if the delimiter is in the data, the splitting into values requires a little more cleverness.

This uses table.rows to get the row, then row.cells to get the cell and inserts the value. Columns and rows are zero indexed, and for rows includes the header and footer (if they exist). You can also use the tbody.rows if the header rows should be skipped.

```js
var data = 'Major;1;2;29\nMinor;2;3;29';

function insertData(id, data) {

  // Show data
  console.log(data);  

  // Get the table
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  // Split the data into records
  var dataRows = data.split(/\n/);

  // Split each row into values and insert in table
  if (table) {
    dataRows.forEach(function(s) {
      var x = s.split(';');
      table.rows[x[2]].cells[x[1]].textContent = x[0];
    });
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
}
td, th {
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table id="t0">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>col 0<th>col 1<th>col 2
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<td><td>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<td><td>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<td><td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="insertData('t0', data)">Insert data</button>
```

Comment: A big thank you! Rob,what do you think what is the difficulty level for this? and there is no /n to divide the row from another and that is a problem on itself!

Comment: I would put it at a very low level, it's basic string and DOM stuff. If you don't have a line delimiter, how do you find each record? Is it just each each set of 4 delimited values represents a record?

Comment: `code var data = document.getElementById("csvfile"); code` when I pass the file as an input it gives me Cannot read property 'split' of null,the record is in a new line not separated from /n,so yes 4 values represent a record

Comment: Rob please help till the very end!The only thing left for me to do is how to upload that csv file so that I can can use after